# asp.net and Oracle single quote auto escape

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, oracle11g

Normally ASP.Net (I think it's .NET doing it) will do magic with single quotes when calling a procedure.  For example the following will work just fine...

```
dim aThing as string = "you're not as cool as your dog"
...
cmd.CommandText = "pkg_cool.s_you"
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("iSomeVar", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = aThing
cmd.executeNonQuery()
```

The package has a simple update query

```
insert into someTable (colName)values(iSomeVar)
```

Now if I do the same thing in ASP, but change the package to use `execute immediate` the single quotes need to be escaped; I did it in asp `replace(aThing,"'","''")`. Can someone explain why?

```
-- the following will work fine if the asp variable "aThing" does not contain an apostrophe.
execute immediate
'insert into ' || vTableName || '(' || colName || ')values(''' || iSomeVar || ''')';
```

`SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the RDBMS (Relational Database Management System) that escapes the apostrophe, not .NET.  I'm guessing `execute immediate` uses the literal string because it's designed for assembling dynamic SQL.

Comment: i assume you mean the asp specific drivers? if i were to do the same thing in coldfusion I can use the preserveSingleQuotes function forcing CF to pass a single quote so that's handled before the RDBMS gets it.

Comment: Well obviously in your example .NET is not populating the parameter with an escaped apostrophe.  ADO.NET doesn't know what the contents of the package is.  I'm not familiar with CF but ORMs like Entity Framework will actually read the package and try to interpret it (it's not very good at that).  Maybe CF does something similar.

Comment: I don't know how drivers work or how the different technologies use them so I won't pretend to. What you're saying makes seance to me.  Oracle says, "this variable is in an `execute immediate` block, I better not mess with it." I'd like to think Oracle is smart like that... but it's stupid in a lot of ways I think it should be smarter. LoL

Comment: I tried to find some solid documentation for you but it's hard sifting through all the non-related articles.  I remember learning that all ADO.NET does is make sure the DB knows that a value is a parameter and the DB takes it from there.

Comment: I couldn't find anything either and it doesn't seem anyone is disagreeing with you.  Thanks for the assist.